# can someone help me with a SQL Error: ORA-02270?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ddl

Can some one help me with this error. Maybe you have sharper eyes. I checked the code ton of times but still can't find it. What I want to do is make `KODAS_UŽ` foreign key for `UŽSAKYTOS_DALYS` table.

```
CREATE TABLE UŽSAKYMAI
    (KODAS_UŽ NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL,
     ID_USS NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL,
     DATA_UŽ DATE NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE UŽSAKYMAI ADD CONSTRAINT UŽSAKYMAI_PK PRIMARY KEY (KODAS_UŽ,ID_USS);

CREATE TABLE UŽSAKYTOS_DALYS 
    (NR NUMERIC(3,0) NOT NULL,
     KODAS_DLS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     KODAS_UKS NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL,
     ID_USS NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE UŽSAKYTOS_DALYS ADD CONSTRAINT UŽ_PK PRIMARY KEY (NR, KODAS_DLS, KODAS_UKS);

ALTER TABLE UŽSAKYTOS_DALYS ADD CONSTRAINT UŽSAKYTOS_DALYS_DALYS_FK FOREIGN KEY (KODAS_DLS)
REFERENCES DALYS(KODAS_D) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

it doesn't work from here

```
ALTER TABLE UŽSAKYTOS_DALYS ADD CONSTRAINT UŽSAKYTOS_DALYS_UŽSAKYMAI_FK FOREIGN KEY (KODAS_UKS)
REFERENCES UŽSAKYMAI(KODAS_UŽ) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Error code:

```
SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list 02270. 00000 - "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list" 
*Cause: A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action: Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS catalog view
```

Comment: Is this sql-server or oracle? What error are you getting?

Comment: @mmmmmpie it's oracle
that's the error: SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
           gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
           key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
           catalog view

Comment: And which `CREATE` or `ALTER` statement is generating the error? Have you tested each one in turn to be sure of it?

Comment: What's unclear about "*A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary key constraint*"?

Comment: I think you need to reference ALL the primary key's, not just a part of it.

Comment: @Andrew Leach I'm green at this :DD I run every statement separatly. I created a tables, already added constraints to some of them. Those two last rows gived me an error... I am not sure what generating it... everything worked until I tried to run thos two rows...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what is unclear tha eather I dont understand what thi error means or something is wrong what I don't.
I cheacked all names of a columns and everything matches

Comment: @HoneyBadge can you tell me please how to do it... I am not sure how to write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE UŽSAKYTOS_DALYS ADD CONSTRAINT UŽSAKYTOS_DALYS_UŽSAKYMAI_FK FOREIGN KEY (KODAS_UKS, ID_USS)
    REFERENCES UŽSAKYMAI(KODAS_UŽ, ID_USS) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This is my best guess, I'm not too familiar with Oracle, or foreign keys in general. I only make them very occasionally (read: basically never).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the primary key of the referenced table has *two* columns, but you are trying to create a foreign key to it consisting of just *one* column.

Here's the table def:

```
CREATE TABLE UŽSAKYMAI
    (KODAS_UŽ NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL,
     ID_USS NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL,
     DATA_UŽ DATE NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE UŽSAKYMAI ADD CONSTRAINT UŽSAKYMAI_PK
  PRIMARY KEY (KODAS_UŽ,ID_USS);
```

And here's your attempt at referencing it:

```
ALTER TABLE UŽSAKYTOS_DALYS ADD CONSTRAINT UŽSAKYTOS_DALYS_UŽSAKYMAI_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (KODAS_UKS) REFERENCES UŽSAKYMAI(KODAS_UŽ)
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Try adding the `ID_USS` column to your foreign key def:

```
ALTER TABLE UŽSAKYTOS_DALYS ADD CONSTRAINT UŽSAKYTOS_DALYS_UŽSAKYMAI_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (KODAS_UKS, ID_USS) REFERENCES UŽSAKYMAI(KODAS_UŽ, ID_USS)
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Or simply, because you're referencing the primary key, you may omit the referenced columns:

```
ALTER TABLE UŽSAKYTOS_DALYS ADD CONSTRAINT UŽSAKYTOS_DALYS_UŽSAKYMAI_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (KODAS_UKS, ID_USS) REFERENCES UŽSAKYMAI
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```